# bidirectional binding on value passed as @Input to a Child

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have 2 components : `Parent` and `Child`.The `Child` receive a `Filter` type as `@Input` from the `Parent`.

The `Filter` look like this :

```
export class FilterModel {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

In the `Parent` template I have this (the `filter` has been initialized in the .ts file) :

```
<app-child [filter]="filter"></app-child>
```

In the `Child` :

```
@Input() filter:FilterModel;
```

The values of `filter` are ok in the `ngOnInit` of the `Child`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.filter);  
  }
```

I can see the value of `filter` in the `Child` template when I do this `{‌{filter.name}}`

I can see the value in the input when I do this :

```
<input type="text" [(value)]="filter.name" >
```

But when I tried to do a bidirectional data binding with `[(ngModel)]`:
 
I got this error:
*Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.*

The `FormsModule` is imported.

Do you know how solve this ?

Later in the `Parent` I'll subscribe to filter value to call a function when the value change.

Thanks for your help,

**Update 1**

```
/src
|
|   /app
|   |
|   |   /models (where filter is)
|   |   /pages
|   |   |
|   |   |   /Myfolder
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   /Child
|   |   |   |   /Parent
|   |   |   |   myfolder.module.ts
|   |   |
|   |   /services
|   |   /theme (I bought a theme)
|   |   |
|   |   |   /compononents (of the theme
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   /applications
|   |   |   |   /sidebar
|   |   |   |   /menu
|   |   pages.module.ts
|   |   pages.compononent.ts
|   app.modules.ts
|   app.compononent.ts
```

`import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` is present in all `.module.ts`

**Update 2**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
import { DirectivesModule } from '../../theme/directives/directives.module';
import { ChildComponent } from './myfolder/child.component';
import { ParentComponent } from './myfolder/parent.component';

export const routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'XXXXX', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'parent', component: ParentComponent, data: { breadcrumb: 'XXXXX' } }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    ParentComponent,
    ChildComponent
  ]
})
export class MyFolderModule { }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the syntax, but usually I see model binding with `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[(value)]`

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt it's what I said when I use [(value)] it's ok but when I use [(ngModel)] I got an error.

Comment: oh yeah alright, now I understand.

Comment: I managed to get it to work in an example I set up myself, there shouldn't be any problem, show us where you import FormsModule, and the structure of your modules/app

Comment: @JoshuaChan the question has been updated

Comment: you need to add FormsModule in the imports array of the module that has the component that uses that <input>

Comment: Unable to reproduce your issue [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i1syta)

Comment: @JoshuaChan it's imported in pages.modules.ts, myfolder.modules.ts, in the .ts of parent and child .. :(

Comment: show me the NgModule contents of myfolder.module.ts

Comment: @JoshuaChan See update 2. I clean the route path but it's correct because the navigation work it's "just" the bindiing

Comment: add FormsModule below CommonModule in the array. You are only importing the module but not registering it for Angular to know.

Comment: @JoshuaChan I added to the array but still same result.

Comment: Are you still getting `can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.` ?

Comment: @JoshuaChan You are right was an another message. The <div> was in a form. Answer the question I will mark as answerd by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngModel is a directive in FormsModule, to use the module you need to add it in the imports array of your NgModule, not just importing it into your script.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule, // add this line
    NgxDatatableModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `FormsModule` into `imports` array.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
 ...
)
```